# extract all elements in a string matching a list

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x

I need help with re.findall. I have a list of states in america in lower case  letters, called states_names, and a string with 1375 laws from different states, called art_str. I need to make a list with the state name for each law.
    state_names = ['district of columbia', 'georgia', 'new jersey', 'illinois']

```
art_str = "2.  45 d.c. reg. 9252, issue: volume 45, number 52, issue date: december 25,
1998, subject: boards, commissions, and agencies, agency: chief financial
officer office of grants management & development, district of columbia
register
... agencies, and community-based and faith-based organizations; * public
and private  ...

3.  46 d.c. reg. 408, issue: volume 46, number 3, issue date: january 15, 1999,
subject: ceremonial resolution, district of columbia register
... years of community, educational and faith-based service to the district
of columbia. ..."
```

For now I have used the following code, which almost gives me the correct answer for law nr. 3, but not law nr. 2:

I split the laws up so I look at one at the time:

```
results = re.finditer("\\n\n[0-9]+. +",art_str) 

for r in results:

    st = r.span()[1]
    sub_str = art_str[st:st+200] # takes the first 200 characters of the law (this is the title where the state name is in)#
    state = re.findall(r"(?=("+'|'.join(state_names)+r"))",sub_str) 
    state_list.append(state)
```

This gives me the correct answer in most of the cases, except the ones where the state name is at the end of the line. Any idea how I can modify my re.findall so I get ALL state names not matter where it is in the text?

Thank you in advance,
Lena

Comment: How can we help you with a regular expression if you don't show us some examples of the strings you are trying to match, and the text you are searching over?

Comment: Why the `+` and the `.` at the end? Did you mean `.` as in "any character" or "end of sentence"? Have you tried just the `'|'.join`ed list of states, enclosed in `\b` for word-boundary?

Comment: Thank you Cory, I have added the information you asked now. And Tobias, I added the +. at the end to make sure that it would take no matter what is behind it. But it doesn't make any difference whether it is there or not...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is that your arbitrary cutoff length, at 200 characters, is too short.

In your failing example, with law number 2, "district of columbia" doesn't start until character 202, and doesn't end until character 221.

However, if you attempt to correct the problem by selecting too large a cutoff length, you might end up reading the states that belong to the law that comes after the one you intend.

The bottom line is that you can never know if any given fixed size limit is too short or too long. You need to devise a method of determining exactly where each law starts and ends, and split each law into its own separate string before performing your search.

So, something like this:

```
laws = re.split('\n\n(?=\d+\.\s{2})', art_str)
for law in laws:
    state_list = [state for state in state_names if state in law]
```